# Ubuntu-Touch can not load on nexus 5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Good day!
I have some problem with booting my nexus 5 after installing ubuntu-touch.
It freezes on load with Google label.
Could you help please.

Comment: try re-flashing the device - also which version did you flash, where did you download, what instructions did you follow.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu touch is not officially supported for Nexus 5 and I think we can't support unofficial ports here, like we can't support unofficial spins of Ubuntu desktop. There are other good channels though, in both chat and mailinglists. Look at the bottom of this page for details: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Contribute#Discuss

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 5 is supported by ubport and has a great installer. Try again now.